# definitely memory loss on valgrind

Tags: fortran, valgrind

I have this part of the following Fortran code, where at `allocate(temp)`, valgrind says about definitely memory loss. Is there any mistake in the way I am doing on allocating this data?

```
subroutine insert_linked_list_grids(l,ncell,nclust,corner,headlev)
    implicit none

    integer :: ig, jg, kg, k, l, m1, m2, m3, nx, ny, nz, ncell, &
         nclust, bsaux, bnaux, bwaux, beaux, bbaux, btaux

    double precision :: dx, dy, dz, dxaux, dyaux, dzaux

    double precision, dimension(24,maxcl) :: corner

    type(level_components1), pointer :: temp, curr
    type(level_components1), dimension(ltop), target :: headlev


    dx    = headlev(l)%hx
    dy    = headlev(l)%hy
    dz    = headlev(l)%hz
    dxaux = headlev(l-1)%hx
    dyaux = headlev(l-1)%hy
    dzaux = headlev(l-1)%hz

    !nullify(headlev(l)%next)
    curr => headlev(l)
    headlev(l)%npatches = 0

    !calculating ix, iy, iz, mx, my, mz
    write(*,*) 'total number of cluster =', nclust
    do k=1,nclust 

       headlev(l)%npatches = headlev(l)%npatches +1

       ig = nint(r*(corner(1,k) - 0.5d0*dxaux - a1)/dxaux ) + 1 
       jg = nint(r*(corner(2,k) - 0.5d0*dyaux - a2)/dyaux ) + 1
       kg = nint(r*(corner(3,k) - 0.5d0*dzaux - a3)/dzaux ) + 1

       !write(*,*) "cluster = ", k,"ig = ", ig,"jg = ", jg,&
       !        "kg = ",kg

       nx = nint(r*(corner(10,k)-corner(1,k) + dxaux)/dxaux)
       ny = nint(r*(corner(5,k)-corner(2,k)  + dyaux)/dyaux)
       nz = nint(r*(corner(15,k)-corner(3,k) + dzaux)/dzaux)

       !write(*,*) "cluster = ", k,"nx = ", nx,"ny = ", ny,&
       !        "nz = ",nz

       call bc_linked_list(ig,jg,kg,nx,ny,nz,dx,dy,dz,bwaux,beaux,&
            bsaux,bnaux,bbaux,btaux,headlev) 

       allocate(temp)

       temp%grid%ix = ig
       temp%grid%iy = jg
       temp%grid%iz = kg
       temp%grid%mx = nx
       temp%grid%my = ny
       temp%grid%mz = nz
       temp%grid%iu = 1 + ncell
       temp%grid%bw = bwaux
       temp%grid%be = beaux
       temp%grid%bs = bsaux
       temp%grid%bn = bnaux
       temp%grid%bb = bbaux
       temp%grid%bt = btaux

       m1 = temp%grid%mx + 1 + 2*nbc
       m2 = temp%grid%my + 1 + 2*nbc
       m3 = temp%grid%mz + 1 + 2*nbc
       ncell = ncell + m1*m2*m3

       nullify(temp%next)
       curr%next => temp
       curr => temp


    end do

    return

  end subroutine insert_linked_list_grids
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include which compiler you are using and what the exact error is.

Comment: ==26020== 1,440 bytes in 15 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 20 of 45
==26020==    at 0x4C2ABED: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

Comment: the error I get after a long time of the code running, is a segmentation fault, that I expect to be in this subroutine, as long as is the only wrong thing I got on valgrind

Comment: the compiller is the intel 13.0

Comment: It looks like this procedure creates a linked list.  Somewhere there is presumably code that "un-creates" this list.  If not - there's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I expect that valgrind is warning you that when the subroutine returns `temp` goes out of scope and is, in effect, reaped, but the memory pointed to by `temp` is not reaped; this looks like a canonical memory leak to me.

You could deallocate `temp` before the subroutine ends.

Or you could make `temp` an allocatable array in which case it is the compiler's responsibility to generate code which reaps the memory allocated when the subroutine returns.  In general, with a modern (Fortran 2003) compiler `allocatable` is a better route to managing memory dynamically than `pointer` because the compiler takes care of memory deallocation. Of course, there are some cases where only a pointer will do.

Comment: Deallocation nullifies, but nullification doesn't [necessarily] deallocate.